# Let $|G|=pqr$ s.t $p<q<r$ and $q\nmid r-1$, $p,q,r$ primes then $G$ has normal subgroups of order $q,r$ or $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $|G|=pqr$ s.t $p<q<r$ and $q\nmid r-1$, $p,q,r$ primes then $G$ has normal subgroups of order $q,r$ or $p$

We know that a group of such order must have a normal Sylow subgroup of some order. Say $H$ and assume $|H|\neq p$,  and let $K$ be a sylow subgroup for another prime that is not $p$. Then $HK$ is a cyclic subgroup and it is normal as its index is $p$. Thus $HK$ is normal, and $H,K$ are characteristic in $HK$ and so both are normal in $G$. Thus $H,K$ are normal in $G$. Is this correct? Can this result be strengthened somehow? By showing additional normal subgroups or loosening the division condition?

Answer (score 1):

The groups $S_3\times C_5$ and $C_3\times D_{10}$ show that you have the maximum number of normal subgroups. The group $C_2\times F_{21}$ (the group $C_7\rtimes C_3$, the normalizer of a Sylow $7$-subgroup of $A_7$) shows you cannot relax the non-divisibility condition. The group $F_{42}=C_7\rtimes C_6$ (the normalizer in $S_7$) shows that relaxing the divisibility condition does not allow you to still have two normal subgroups of prime order.

The minimum number of (proper, non-trivial) normal subgroups is two, because $G$ is soluble.